# ArrayOutofBounds Exception even though it checks if the square is on the edge

Tags: java

This code is part of the code for my Conway's Game of Life simulation. This particular method is a 'step', advancing the game forward by one generation. 
There seems to be an error when it attempts to check if the square straight up is true or false (this is a 10 x 10 boolean array at the moment). The code's intention is to check every square and count how many neighbors each square has. I have if statements making it so that the squares on the edges and corners go under special conditions (e.g. the one in the top right doesn't check for the squares straight up, top right, and directly right)

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
    at Life.step(Life.java:71)
```

The error is above and Line 71 is the if statement that checks for a neighbor straight down

```
public void step() {
        System.out.println("Step");
        System.out.println(cells.length);
        System.out.println(cells[0].length);
        boolean[][] nextCells = new boolean[cells.length][cells[0].length];
        for (int row = 0; row < cells.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; row < cells[0].length; col++) {
                int neighborCount = 0;
                // checks for neighbor straight down
                if (row > 0 && cells[row - 1][col] == true) {
                    neighborCount++;
                }
                // lower right
                if (row > 0 && col < cells[0].length - 1 && cells[row - 1][col + 1] == true) {
                    neighborCount++;
                }
                // right
                if (col < cells[0].length - 1 && cells[row][col + 1] == true) {
                    neighborCount++;
                }
                // upper right
                if (row < cells.length - 1 && col < cells[0].length - 1 && cells[row + 1][col + 1] == true) {
                    neighborCount++;
                }
                // straight up
                if (row < cells.length - 1 && cells[row + 1][col] == true) {
                    neighborCount++;
                }
                // upper left
                if (row < cells.length - 1 && col > 0 && cells[row + 1][col - 1] == true) {
                    neighborCount++;
                }
                // left
                if (col > 0 && cells[row][col - 1] == true) {
                    neighborCount++;
                }
                // lower left
                if (row > 0 && col > 0 && cells[row - 1][col - 1]) {
                    neighborCount++;
                }
```

Comment: On which line does the problem occur?

Comment: The condition in this loop isn't what you want it to be: `for (int col = 0; row < cells[0].length; col++)` (You should be checking col, not row...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the line *above* where the error is being thrown:

`for (int col = 0;`**`row`**`< cells[0].length; col++) {`

This should be:

`for (int col = 0;`**`col`**`< cells[row].length; col++) {`

Comment: Oh lord. That was a bad mistake on my part. I always seem to overlook the simpler things.